# Homomorphism with additive property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, pell-type-equations

If I have a mapping $N:R \longrightarrow T$ where both $R, \; T$ are rings with the properties:
$N(e) = e$
$N(ab) = N(a)N(b)$
$N(a+b) \not = N(a) + N(b)$.
What do we call this? Is this a multiplicative group homomorphism?

I am trying to prove that $N:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$
$N(\alpha) = a^2 - Db^2$

is a homomorphism.

Comment: If $N$ is not additive, how can it be a hom? You have $N(a+b)\neq N(a)+N(b)$.

Comment: Exactly, and it's not a group hom. as $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a group under multiplication....

Comment: You could call it a monoid homomorphism where both rings have the multiplicative monoid structure.

Comment: As far as I know, this is usually just called a multiplicative map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would just call it a multiplicative function.  As for the function $N$ you are considering, it is the restriction of a *group homomorphism* $N$ from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})^{\ast}$ to $\mathbb{Q}^{\ast}$, where here if $K$ is a field, $K^{\ast} := K \setminus \{0\}$ is a group with respect to multiplication.  This homomorphism is called the norm.  It of course can be extended to take the value $0$, without losing the property that $N(xy) = N(x) N(y)$.